# Shopify Python - Set inventory quantity

Tags: python, shopify

I'm trying to set inventory quantity of a product in shopify using the [Shopify Python Api](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api).

As i understand it, i need to set the 'inventory_level' of the 'inventory_item' that belongs to the product, but after a few days of searching and testing i still have no luck.

**Where i'm at**
I have my products showing up in my store with all the data but the inventory quantity.

I'm not sure how to proceed as there's not a whole lot of documentation.

**Here's my code for creating a product**

```
def CreateShopifyProduct(data):
    # CREATE PRODUCT
    product = shopify.Product()
    # Add stuff to product, variant and inventoryItem here
    product.title = data['title']
    #product.status = ""
    #product.tags = data['tags']
    product.body_html = data['description']
    if 'catagory' in data:
        product.product_type = data['category']

    if 'vendor' in data:
        product.vendor = data['vendor']

    if 'image_url' in data:
        image_path = data['image_url']
        image = shopify.Image()
        image.src = image_path
        product.images = [image]
    else:
        try:
            image = GetLocalImageFiles(data['id'])
            product.images = [image]
            
        except:
            print("No local images found")
    
    success = product.save() #returns false if the record is invalid
    
    
    # CREATE VARIANT
    variant = shopify.Variant()
    
    if 'ean' in data:
        variant.barcode = data['ean']
    variant.price = data['gross_price']
    variant.weight = data['weight']
    #variant.count = data['inventory']
    variant.inventory_management = 'shopify'
    
    product.variants = [variant]
    variant.product_id = product.id
    s = variant.save()
    success = product.save() #returns false if the record is invalid
    
    # CREATE INVENTORYITEM
    inventoryItem = shopify.InventoryItem()
    #inventoryItem = variant.inventory_item
    inventoryItem.tracked = True
    inventoryItem.id = product.id
    variant.inventory_quantity = data['inventory']
    inventoryItem.inventory_quantity = data['inventory']
    variant.inventory_item = inventoryItem
    
    s = variant.save()
    success = product.save()
    #ii = inventoryItem.save() # this returns 406
    
    #inv_level = shopify.InventoryLevel.find(inventory_item_ids=6792364982390, location_ids=61763518582)
    #quantity = inv_level[0].__dict__['attributes']['available']
    #shopify.InventoryLevel.set(location_id=61763518582, inventory_item_id=variant.inventory_item.id, available=data['inventory'])  
    #shopify.InventoryLevel.connect(61763518582, variant.inventory_item.id)
    

    if product.errors:
        #something went wrong, see new_product.errors.full_messages() for example
        print("error")
        print(product.errors.full_messages())
```

If i try to set the InventoryLevel with

```
shopify.InventoryLevel.set(61527654518, inventoryItem.id, 42)
# or
shopify.InventoryLevel.set(location_id=61527654518, inventory_item_id=inventoryItem.id, available=17)
```

I recieve a

```
pyactiveresource.connection.ResourceNotFound: Not Found: https://domain.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-07/inventory_levels/set.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You need three things to update an inventory level. One, you need a valid location ID. Two, you need the inventory item ID. Finally, you need the amount to adjust inventory to, that will adjust the inventory there to match your needs.

You should really play at the command-line and ensure you can quickly get the information you need, then try your updates. In other words, ensure you are getting a good location ID, inventory item ID and finally, that you know the amount of inventory already in Shopify. Since you have to calculate a delta change, these are the minimum steps most people take.

Note that once you get good at doing one item, you'll realize Shopify also accepts up to 100 at a time, making your updates a lot faster.